# What's the meaning of "out of fear"?

Tags: meaning

> "We choose our path out of fear. "

Does it mean:

(A) We choose this path because of fear;

or

(B) We choose this path to get rid of fear.

If the meaning is (A), then could I make a sentence in the meaning of (B) with "out of fear".

Comment: If you do something _out of [an emotion]_, you do it because you feel that emotion.

Comment: Apparently there's a theme park in Maine called [Fear Town Haunted House](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g41805-d10448715-Reviews-Fear_Town_Haunted_House-Seekonk_Massachusetts.html). I suppose you _could_ say "The theme park scared us so much that **out of fear we made our way out of Fear**"

Comment: It's ambiguous; without the context we cannot tell what it means. Although people may guess based on what is more common to say. "We choose our way out of the jungle" is unambiguous, by contrast.

Answer (score 1):

It is the following connotation of ***[out of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/out-of)***:

> used to show the reason why someone does something:

> *I took the job out of necessity because we had no money left.
> You might like to come and see what we're doing out of interest (= because I think you might be interested).*

Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

It is OED sense 4 of the phrase ***out of***, meaning "by reason of".

> 4.a. From (something) as a cause or motive; as the result or effect of; because or by reason of.

The OED has examples of its use dating from 1225.